# Grant privileges on SAP HANA trial account

Tags: csv, cloud, hana

I'm trying to load a CSV into my SAP HANA trial account (HCP) using HANA Studio.
I created a table and executed the following code:

```
IMPORT FROM CSV FILE 'C:/Users/.../data.csv'   
INTO "NEO_123..."."MYTABLE"  
WITH RECORD DELIMITED BY '\n'  
FIELD DELIMITED BY ',';
```

But I'm getting this error:

> Could not execute 'IMPORT FROM CSV FILE 'C:/Users/.../data.csv' INTO ...'
>
> SAP DBTech JDBC: [258]: insufficient privilege: Not authorized

Loading a CSV with the Import-Dialog (File->Import->SAP HANA Content->Data from Local File) works, but I want to load it with my code.

I think I need to grant some privileges, but is it even possible on a trial account?

Comment: I am not fully familiar with the trial accounts. But for the csv-import to work in hana-sql the file needs to be placed on the server with the path, which is specified with the csv_import_path_filter parameter. The Import privilege must also be granted to your user. Do you fulfill both requirements?

Comment: @Dencrash: Ok, I didn't know I have to place the file on a server. I just had it on my local machine. Do you know where I can find more information about that (e.g. URL)?

Comment: You could try these posts  [1](http://scn.sap.com/community/hana-in-memory/blog/2014/04/10/tips-for-loading-large-csv-files-to-hana),[2](http://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/inmemory/Importing+CSV+files+into+SAP+HANA)

Answer (score 0):

You can grant the Import privilege using:

```
GRANT IMPORT TO <grantee>
```

Sadly, I do not know, if this can be done with the trial account. For further information on the granting of privileges, you can use the [HANA-documentation](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/20/f674e1751910148a8b990d33efbdc5/content.htm).